# How can I debug Cisco Firewall ASA "Dispatch Unit" very high CPU utilisation from ASDM?

Tags: firewall, cisco, cisco-asa

I have recently had my first firewall installed so I am very new to this whole situation. I am finding that Dispatch unit is becoming overloaded and it would appear to be the reason I get serious bouts of lag on my server.
The firewall has had little configuration apart from me blocking all the ports in "Access Rules" and allowing only the ones the server needs and from where it needs them.

I guess what I am after is assistance with locating the issues causing "Dispatch Unit" to take up all the CPU

Regards

--Edit--

With ASDM statistics I found that packets inbound (peak of 70-100k/sec from <1k/sec normal), traffic inbound (peak of 40-50kbits/sec from <1kbits/sec normal) and CPU all peak at the same time so I am pretty sure it is an attack of some sort but as a beginner with ASA I am not sure how to resolve

Answer (score 1):

The first thing you may check is the traffic through firewall. Please give the result of this command:

> **show int**
>
> **show traff**
>
> **show perfmon**

to determind what traffic cause your problem.

Using CLI, don't using ASDM (And I never use it), it makes your ASA load increase.

Comment: Thanks, I guess I will have to wait for the next episode of this overload before I get useful results. Anything I can do in the meantime?

Comment: show your inspection settings. If it is default, you should make some change, i.e turn off icmp and icmp error inspection

Comment: In Configuration > Service Policy Rules > inspection_default? I removed icmp.
When I try those commands I get errors such as: ERROR: % Invalid input detected at '^' marker.

Comment: It seems you have typed wrong. I don't use ASDM, you can make in CLI like this:

`policy-map global_policy`
`class inspection_default`
`no inspect icmp`
`no inspect icmp error`

Comment: I got the 3 sets of data after upgrading from access level 1 to 15. I have been waiting for an incident to see how they will compare but no trouble so far.
I cannot get the policy-map to work however just get the error "Invalid input detected at '^' marker" pointing to the 'o'
I am more and more weary that this is possibly an attack of some kind.
Regards

Comment: With ASDM statistics I found that packets inbound (peak of 70-100k/sec from <1k/sec normal), traffic inbound (peak of 40-50kbits/sec from <1kbits/sec normal) and CPU all peak at the same time so I am pretty sure it is an attack of some sort

Comment: Detected millions of GGP-3 packets 100k/sec but find very little information on this. Cannot access via putty to do the above commands

Comment: Use console instead of putty (SSH), I can't help you without information from above command.

Comment: What is "console"? The company only advised me to use ASDM 
Regards

Comment: Cisco device have a console port that you can use it to access and config cisco device.

Comment: The firewall is at the datacentre though I don't think that is possible